# nodeos allow connection from any ip?

Tags: nodeos, port-to-eos

I was doing this [tutorial](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-home/docs/getting-the-software). Locally it works fine, but I need to remotely access the endpoint via `curl http://my.ip.adreess:8888/v1/chain/get_info`

But it doesn't work and I am sure it isn't my ubuntu firewall. The command showed (`nodeos -e -p ... ...`) in the link. Does it allow remote connections?

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
cleos -u http://my.ip.adreess:8888 get info
```

Make sure you are runnig nodeos at the port `8888`

Comment: i found the solution. just modify the value for http-server-address within the config.ini file